# how to find data between two dates in a two different columns?

Tags: mysql, select

Am working on a hotel management project, on issue of room availability I need more codes, here is a link of an image[https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qlbl.png].
By using the following codes

```
SELECT b.check_in, b.check_out, r.room_no, r.room_id 
FROM room r JOIN booking b 
ON r.room_id = b.room_id  
WHERE 
  r.room_id = $room_no 
  AND b.check_in <= '$check_in_date' AND b.check_out >= '$check_out_date'
```

Up to now it check availability between two date let's say a room is being booked from 15/8/2019 - 20/8/2019, once it is booked a system reject. But once it is booked let's say 18/8/2019 - 22/8/2019 system accepts it.

Any one can help me to add some codes so the room can be rejected.
Much thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking. The bookings that do *not* overlap with the dates in question can be selected with:

```
SELECT room_id FROM booking
WHERE '$checkin_date' >= check_out OR '$checkout_date' <= check_in
```

Therefore, the rooms that are not available because of existing bookings can be selected with:

```
SELECT room_id FROM booking
WHERE '$checkin_date' <= check_out AND '$checkout_date' >= check_in
```

So, if you are looking for a booking that would be the cause of rejecting a new booking because of overlapping booking dates, then you should modify your SQL to:

```
SELECT b.check_in, b.check_out, r.room_no, r.room_id 
FROM room r JOIN booking b 
ON r.room_id = b.room_id  
WHERE 
  r.room_id = $room_no 
  AND '$checkin_date' <= b.check_out AND '$checkout_date' >= b.check_in
```

If you are looking for all rooms that are available for booking between two dates based upon what has already been booked, then:

```
SELECT check_in, check_out, room_no, room_id FROM room WHERE room_id NOT IN (
    SELECT room_id FROM booking
        WHERE '$checkin_date' <= check_out AND '$checkout_date' >= check_in
)
```

Or for those who prefer using joins, the following should return the same results:

```
SELECT r.check_in, r.check_out, r.room_no, r.room_id FROM room r LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT room_id FROM booking
        WHERE '$checkin_date' <= check_out AND '$checkout_date' >= check_in
) sq ON r.room_id = sq.room_id
WHERE sq.room_id is NULL
```

Comment: Thanks alot Mr. Aaronson, let me work on your answers then i will give you feedback.